# Programmatically change the Base URL?

Tags: 7, hooks, i18n-l10n

Is there any way to programmatically change the Base URL, Just as the "locale" module does..
My Website is multi-lingual which has to recognize 3rd argument, after the language identifier. Some custom code will be triggered when base on the third argument.

Have tried to Find a solution for this but the most of the Solutions suggest settings.php approach.

I am looking for a hook that will allow me to alter the third parameter in the URL for custom functionality.

Sample URL: www.example.com/hi/arg3
Above "hi" is the language identifier and "arg3" will be used for custom functionality. Hence a node to be rendered will have url as  www.example.com/hi/arg3/node/1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that with:

[`hook_url_outbound_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_url_outbound_alter/7)

Keep in mind all URLs run through that function so your hook implementation should be as fast as possible.

Example from locale module:

> Rewrite outbound URLs with language based prefixes:[`locale_url_outbound_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!locale!locale.module/function/locale_url_outbound_alter/7)

See also: [`Language Negotiation API`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!language.inc/group/language_negotiation/7)

Comment: Oops I managed to downvote this instead of upvote it for some reason. Sorry 'bout that, I've reversed it. Congrats on getting to 10k by the way :)

Comment: Thanks for the solution, will try it out and comment once successfully done

Comment: Callback from local_url_outbound_alter goes to  [locale_language_url_rewrite_url](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21locale.inc/function/locale_language_url_rewrite_url/7)